# How can I set different icons for App Store and homescreen?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, icons, app-store

I know all the icons of an application should be equal, but I'm developing an app that **needs** a different icon for the App Store.

How do I set it in Xcode? I cannot find this in the documentation.

Comment: You are kind of contradicting yourself by saying I know I cant do it but I want to do it! Explain little more what exactly you need.

Comment: @Cyprian, I need an icon that identifies the application in the App Store and one for the Homescreen for "camouflage" the app. This is a magic trick, so the need to have different icons. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Icons of your app on iOS device homescreens are the ones you include in your project, and icon that is displayed in AppStore on both iOS devices and desktop iTunes is the one you upload via iTunes Connect before submitting your app for review (1024x1024 pixel one).

You can find more info about all of those icons in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html).

Comment: Nice! I just find [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html), that says "57x57px - App Store and the Home screen on iPhone/iPod touch". So I had doubts. Thank you!

Comment: Don't work any more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055908/how-to-use-different-icon-on-app-store