# How to use a different icon for the App Store and device's home screen in applications with image assets?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, xcode5, itunesartwork

The App Store stops showing the icon from iTunes Connect on non-retina computers' displays, and shows the app's icon now for applications with image assets.

How can I use a different icon in the App Store and on the device's home screen for applications with image assets?

An iTunesArtwork file in the application bundle can't help, because it will be shown only on iTunes.

**UPDATED:**

I think we can change one or more images from the image assets and display them in the App Store. But which ones?

Comment: have you been able to do it?

Answer (score -1):

If you use different icons for the application and the Appstore (itunesconnect) your application will be rejected ....

Here is message that I received in the resolution center

> 3.5 - Small and large App icons should be similar, so as to not to cause confusion

so I don't think there is a way to do it

Comment: App Store icon can use "Free" label and etc.

Comment: @Altaveron  What you mean with free label ?